# Is the halting problem a matter of an encoding scheme ?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem, encoding-scheme

I was reading about the halting problem recently, there is a [video](https://youtu.be/92WHN-pAFCs) on youtube where it tries to explain the halting problem easily (since it is complicated to explain).

So, (A,C & H) have different inputs, if we suppose that we can run the three inputs on a machine (x) using one encoding scheme (i.e encoding for chess = arthemtic), would that solve the halting problem ?

Is it a problem of encoding different forms of inputs to the machine itself, or is it a problem of always getting the right answer to the input ?

Comment: Whatever encoding you use, halting problem remains undecidable.

Comment: I would disagree with you on this, if it's an encoding problem, then i can make it always halts.

Comment: Thats what I said. Halting problem is undecidable irrespective of the encoding. You should have a look at how halting problem is proved to be undecidable , the proof nowhere assumes a specific encoding.

Comment: Maybe the video lecture is confusing you. There are dozens of other accounts on the web, some of which you might find more convincing.